# I think i have have a bug in JSON.Net

Tags: debugging, json.net

So I'm a bit of a beginner think i've got some unexpected behaviour/ a bug, though it may well be operator error rather than anything else but either way I'm stumped and don't know what to do.

I'm reading in a JSON string! from 
https://beta-api.betfair.com/exchange/betting/rest/v1/en/navigation/lhm.json

I'm passing it with JSON.Net(v6.0.3 from Nuget) ill get to how in minute, but im getting a error where two of the supposedly unique objects returned have the same ID, something of a problem. While trying to work out where I had mashed it up I looked at the JSON string with the Visual Studio JSON Visualiser and that is showing two different ID's as expected.

Edit
I've uploaded two pictures but had to od it externally and copied in the section of JSON that's relevant.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/G333M.jpg

```
{
                                "children": [
                                    {
                                        "children": [
                                            {
                                                "exchangeId": "1", 
                                                "id": "1.114548892", 
                                                "name": "Moneyline", 
                                                "type": "MARKET"
                                            }
                                        ], 
                                        "id": "27229997", 
                                        "name": "Hamilton @ Calgary", 
                                        "type": "EVENT"
                                    }, 
                                    {
                                        "children": [
                                            {
                                                "exchangeId": "1", 
                                                "id": "1.114548889", 
                                                "name": "Moneyline", 
                                                "type": "MARKET"
                                            }
                                        ], 
                                        "id": "27229996", 
                                        "name": "Toronto @ Ottawa", 
                                        "type": "EVENT"
                                    }
                                ], 
                                "id": "74587734296", 
                                "name": "Games 18 July", 
                                "type": "GROUP"
                            },
```

To fetch the string i am using an object inherited from HTTPclient, with

```
        BFresponce = Await Me.GetAsync(BetFairBetaAddress & RestAddress & Method)
        Dim x = Await BFresponce.Content.ReadAsStringAsync 'not normaly here just so i can veiw the string
        Return JsonConvertHelper.DeserializeObject(Of T)(Await BFresponce.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
```

With my own help function

```
   Public Shared Function DeserializeObject(Of T)(stream As Stream) As T
        Dim serializer As New JsonSerializer()
        Using streamReader As New StreamReader(stream)
            Return serializer.Deserialize(streamReader, GetType(T))
        End Using
    End Function
```

And the class beeing passed in T is

```
Namespace BetFairNS
Public Class NavigationData
    Public Property name As String
    Public Property id As Single
    Public Property exchangeId As Integer
    Public Property type As NavigationDataType
    Public Property children As List(Of NavigationData)
End Class
Public Enum NavigationDataType
    EVENT_TYPE
    GROUP
    [EVENT]
    MARKET
    RACE
End Enum
```

End Namespace

So the crux of it is have i mashed this up somewhere? or if its a bug what do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with Json.Net.  The JSON data file you linked to has 260 instances of recurring IDs, all of them in the Horse Racing category.  Here are the first 5:

```
Duplicate id found: 1.114591860
Path 1: ROOT > Horse Racing > 1600m 3yo > 1600m 3yo
Path 2: ROOT > Horse Racing > FRA > Chant (FRA) 14th Jul > 1600m 3yo

Duplicate id found: 1.114591859
Path 1: ROOT > Horse Racing > 1600m 3yo > To Be Placed
Path 2: ROOT > Horse Racing > FRA > Chant (FRA) 14th Jul > To Be Placed

Duplicate id found: 1.114591864
Path 1: ROOT > Horse Racing > 1600m 3yo > 1600m 3yo
Path 2: ROOT > Horse Racing > FRA > Chant (FRA) 14th Jul > 1600m 3yo

Duplicate id found: 1.114591863
Path 1: ROOT > Horse Racing > 1600m 3yo > To Be Placed
Path 2: ROOT > Horse Racing > FRA > Chant (FRA) 14th Jul > To Be Placed

Duplicate id found: 1.114591869
Path 1: ROOT > Horse Racing > 1600m Grp1 > 1600m Grp1
Path 2: ROOT > Horse Racing > FRA > Chant (FRA) 14th Jul > 1600m Grp1
```

You can check this simply by downloading the file using a web browser, saving it to disk, then opening it with a text editor and searching for the ID values I've listed.  Each one appears twice, at different places in the hierarchy.

Does it say somewhere in the API documentation for this site that all IDs in the JSON will be distinct?  It looks to me like they simply decided to list the same node at more than one level for browsing convenience (i.e. list all the races directly under "horse racing" and also list them by country/event).  You are probably going to need to change your assumptions about the data and adjust your code accordingly.

**EDIT**
Now that you have shared the actual ID / name of the node that is giving you trouble, the problem is clear.  You've declared the `id` field of your `NavigationData` class as `Single` when it should be `String`.  `Single` is a floating point type, and is not suitable for holding ID values, even if they may have a decimal point in them.

Again, take a closer look at the actual JSON file.  If you search for "Hamilton @ Calgary", you will see that it has an ID of `27229997`.  The other node, "Toronto @ Ottawa", immediately beneath it, has an ID of `27229996`.  In your debugger image, the values both show as `27229996.0`  The IDs are getting mangled most likely because `Single` does not have the capability to represent the number 27229997 exactly as a binary floating point number, so the closest neighboring value is being chosen instead.  This is a very bad thing when you need an exact representation (as you always do with an ID).

The key point is to use the right tool for the job.  You cannot assume that a third-party ID will always be numeric or contain only a single decimal point, and you will never do math operations on an ID.  In short, there's no reason to make it a decimal type.  Declare it as String and that will fix the problem.  I would also recommend the same for the `exchangeId` field for the same reason.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that, guess i will have to change my assumptions, However that's not the issue I was struggling with at the moment.   I have uploaded two pictures to an external host as I cant do it here. They show the JSON result as read in having two ID's 27229996 ive searched the text and that ID only appearers once.

Comment: I would not have tracked that down, can you explain why "27229997" gets truncated to 27229996.0 rather than 27229990 when it runs out of precision? Marked as answer.

Comment: Floating point precision is a huge topic and I am not an expert in this area.  Most likely what is happening is that 27229997 cannot be represented exactly in binary floating point, so the "closest neighboring value" is being chosen instead.  I recommend taking a look at ["What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic"](http://floating-point-gui.de/) to help you understand what is going on.  But the bottom line is, if you need to represent an exact value (as you always do with an ID) then don't use a type that does not always have an exact representation.